# RecycleView how to hide a reveal a top view on scroll (not the toolbar)

Tags: android, view, scroll, hide, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to (inspired by https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part2)) hide a view I have on top of my RecycleView when I scroll up, and display it when scrolled down.

But It doesn't seem to work great. When I scroll up the TextView does disappear but it leave a blank space from the the top to the start of the list view.
(in the case below I use .setTransalteX(dy) on the textView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What kind of layout should I use to archive the same but instead of leaving a blank space when I scroll up, the list takes the space of the textview ?

(Example of app that does this is the result list of Booking.com)
(It doesn't re appear when scroll down, but thats fine.. its the fact that search filter scroll up when the list scroll up)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:paddingTop="44dp"
        android:cliptoPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:paddingTop="44dp" this is not really dynamic..
I have already tried this. (by setting the padding in code depending on the size of the textview) but it does the same effect as when I have the linearLayout (blank space of the size of the padding)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you just want to let textview scroll with Recyclerview,Just add textview as first child of Recyclerview.Or search headerRecyclerView for a simple way.

Comment: Same effect as the two pics. On the first you can see there is a search box (not included in the list view) and a list view. On the 2nd pic, when we scroll the first view scroll with the listiview (even though its not an element of the list view)

Comment: So use a headerRecyclerview is enough. So you said you try my framelayout , did you add android:cliptoPadding="false"?Plz use fixed 44dp  as height ,and try again.

Comment: uuuuh......... magic clipToPadding.... thats makes the view disappear AND doest leave a blank space ! Well done sir

Comment: ClipToPadding means that scrollableview can scroll in their padding.Add TextView in RecyclerView is better.